# Are there performance or functionality issues by connecting USB peripherals in series?

Tags: usb, usb-3

I'm building a PC and would like to anticipate any issues with having my monitor and keyboard far away from the case (further than normal).  I've already verified a 12' DisplayPort cable should handle the 1080p @ 165Hz for my GPU/Monitor combo (RTX 2070S + Asus ROG PG279Q).

However, to reduce the number of cables traveling from my desk to my cabinet, I'd like to connect:

1. My monitor's USB 3.0 upstream port to a USB 3.0 motherboard port (Gigabyte Z390 AORUS Master)
2. My ASUS ROG STRIX Flare Keyboard to my monitor's USB 3.0 downstream port
3. My ASUS ROG Gladius II Origin wired mouse to my Keyboard

It all seems perfectly legitimate that the mouse and keyboard should be fully functional, and I shouldn't experience any degradation in performance.

The monitor and keyboard would simply be acting as a pass-through, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Open source drawings from simpleicons.com]

This? It will work AOK; no problem, no degradation. You could even use USB 1.0 for the mouse and keyboard.

Comment: Love the drawing.  Yes, perfect illustration.  And thank you. I realize it's a rather rudimentary question, but didn't want to start designing a desk solution without knowing these things...  I obviously would have just tested it out, but my components have not yet arrived :/  Thanks again, @K7AAY.  I ticked up your answer, but since I don't have rep in this group I don't think you'll see it.

Comment: Checkmark does appear. I have no problem with rudimentary questions, as I have wasted far too many American pesos on bits and pieces which wouldn't work the way I wanted... You can also add a click on the grey up-arrowhead to show the answer was constructive. Feedback is very useful. More on the issue of voting on answers at https://superuser.com/help/why-vote  Nice rig you got there, BTW.